# How to suppress WildcardImport and MatchingDeclarationName for Detekt?

Tags: kotlin, detekt

I need to suppress two errors: WildcardImport and MatchingDeclarationName. Probleme is that it is need to be applied to the whole file, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to suppress detekt on a class you can put this on the top of your class declaration

```
@Suppress("WildcardImport","MatchingDeclarationName")
class SampleClass
```

Or if you want to suppress the whole file you can put this annotation

```
@file:Suppress("WildcardImport","MatchingDeclarationName")
```